# Date not showing in shell program

Tags: linux, bash

I am using this shell program where i need to display date with time for some particular task. For some reason the date is not working and its only showing time.

```
 date +'%H:%M:%S Calling' >> /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/log.txt #calling
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it

Comment: From the shell, try: `man date` and it will explain all the options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only adding formatting to the `date` command for the time in hours minutes and seconds (i.e. `'%H:%M:%S'`). Try:

```
date +'%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S Calling' >> /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/log.txt #calling
```